# A 9 token game of Nim tree construction

Tags: game-theory

Trying to construct the full tree for a 9 game token of Nim and am slightly confused. I don't understand how two players, min and max, will make their pick. For example, max picks first and can only pick [9]. Min then picks from [8-1], [7-2], [6-3],  and [5-4]. How does min calculate it's utility value here?

```
max                              [9]
min                 [8-1]   [7-2]   [6-3]   [5-4]
max        [7-1-1] [6-2-1] [5-3-1] [5-2-2] [4-3-2] [3-3-2] 
min    [6-1-1-1] [5-2-1-1] [4-3-1-1] [5-1-2-1] [4-2-2-1] [3-3-2-1] [4-1-2-2] [3-2-2-2] [3-1-3-2][2-2-3-2] [2-1-3-2]
```

Comment: I removed the part of your question about checking your working: we don't accept that kind of question because they're not interesting to anybody except the person who did the working, and they don't help anyone understand anything.

Comment: This is not the most common ruleset for Nim. Please explain the source of this problem. (The game seems like it might be [Grundy's Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundy%27s_game) instead of Nim.) The source of the problem (notes? a textbook?) may include the relevant convention for utility value for a combinatorial game like this.